# Что за формат даты?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Выбираю записи с DB(Laravel). Поле `created_at` имеет правильный формат даты:

```
created_at => '2019-04-17 20:00:00'
```

Но при возврате ответа:

```
return response()->json([
           'success' => true,
           'data' => $this->_response
        ]);
```

Дата приходит в вот таком формате:

```
2019-04-17T14:01:29.000000Z
```

Что это за формат? И как по возможности от него избавиться?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 И как по возможности от него избавиться - изменить формат даты там откуда он приходит?

Comment: *Поле created_at имеет правильный формат даты* Вы указали не формат поля, а формат отображения его значения где-то, в каком-то клиенте. Формат поля - это DATETIME, TIMESTAMP и пр. Судя по тому, что вернулось и отобразилось как не надо - формат TIMESTAMP.

Comment: @Akina в базе формат DATETIME.

Comment: А RDBMS какая? если MySQL, скажем, то в нём DATETIME беззонная, и тогда фортель с зоной - это фортель PHP.

Comment: @Akina MySQL, понял, буду рыться в `php`.

Comment: кастануть карбоном и указать формат нужный (это в модели)

Comment: @AndreyIvasko Спасибо за вариант) Сделал так: `$item->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`